# Generating dictionaries and lists in JavaScript after a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm receiving a JSON in this format:

```
{
 "0": {
  "a": 0.0, 
  "b": 1.0, 
  "G": 6.0, 
  "w": 0.0, 
  "F": -1.0
 }, 
 "1": {
  "a": 0.0, 
  "b": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "G": 0.000301361083984375, 
  "w": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "F": -1.0
 }, 
 "2": {
  "a": 0.0, 
  "b": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "G": 0.000301361083984375, 
  "w": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "F": -1.0
 }, 
 "3": {
  "a": 0.0, 
  "b": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "G": 0.000301361083984375, 
  "w": 0.1429004669189453, 
  "F": -1.0
....
```

Let's say I call that a `json` variable. I'm trying to turn it into something like:

```
[
 {"key": "series1",
   values: [
            [`json`["1"]["a"],`json`["1"]["F"]],[`json`["1"]["b"],`json`["1"]["G"]]
           ]
 },
 {"key": "series2",
   values: [
            [`json`["2"]["a"],`json`["2"]["F"]],[`json`["2"]["b"],`json`["2"]["G"]]
           ]
 },
 {"key": "series3",
   values: [
            [`json`["3"]["a"],`json`["3"]["F"]],[`json`["3"]["b"],`json`["3"]["G"]]
           ]
 },
 ....
]
```

I tried this JavaScript for accomplishing it but got lost :S

```
var data = function myData(json) {

        series = {}
        for (iteracion in json) {
            series.push({
                key: iteracion, values: [[x: iteracion['a'], y: iteracion['F']],[x: iteracion['b'], y: iteracion['G']]]
            })
        }

        return series
```

Comment: The format you're trying to map the data into isn't a valid object.
What exactly do you need? I see a lot of redundancy in that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution to your problem is:

```
var result = [];
for (var series in json) {      
  result.push({
    key : 'series' + series,
    values : [
      json[series].a,
      json[series].F,
      json[series].b,
      json[series].G,
    ]
  });
}
```

If you don't really need an array of objects that contain a key and a value, i organized your information slightly better:

```
var result = {};
for (var series in json) {      
  result['series' + series] = [
    json[series].a,
    json[series].F,
    json[series].b,
    json[series].G,
  ];
}
```

This results in something like this:

```
{
  series0 : [ 0, -1, 1, 6 ],
  series1 : [ 0, -1, 0.14, 0.0003],
  ...
}
```